# OpenSUSE: PHP - Unable to execute sudo /usr/sbin/chpasswd

Tags: linux, opensuse, php7

Could somebody give a tip, where can be a problem.
I have a Server with OpenSUSE, PHP7 and roundcube. Plugin "Password" in roundcube fire an error:

```
PHP Error: Password plugin: Unable to execute sudo /usr/sbin/chpasswd in /srv/www/htdocs/roundcubemail/plugins/password/drivers/chpasswd.php
```

sudoers file is changed with manual:

```
nginx ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/chpasswd
Defaults:nginx !requiretty
```

as nginx user, I've tried in shell the command above and had no problem.

in php.ini disable_functions = is empty and safe_mode is Off.

Do someone have an Idea, where could be the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For testing purposes, nginx and php-fpm were started under the root user, but roundcube fired the same error

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in php-fpm.server unit:

```
# Mounts the /usr, /boot, and /etc directories read-only for processes invoked by this unit.
#ProtectSystem=full
```